# How do you calculate square root with nodes?

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I'm creating my own merge functions in the compositor, but I've run into a bit of a wall. How do you calculate the square root with nodes? Would one have to write a python node to do this? If so, what would that look like?

Answer (score 16):

The square root of x equals x^.5, so use a math node set to *Power* and put the value whose square root you want in the upper socket, and set the lower value to .5.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, Duane. I just discovered this myself minutes ago and was about to answer my own question. You beat me to it. Helps a lot.

Comment: To generalize a bit, the nth root is equal to the inverse power, i.e. `root(x, n)` == `x^(1/n)`. So if you wanted, you could construct a node group which divides 1 by the root before feeding it to a power node, and then you'd have a root node.

Comment: @gandalf3 an Absolute node, or similar, too to make sure input is >= 0 ?